# Trying to recreate the standard normal distribution table in R

Tags: r

[https://www.math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ersims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf)

So I need to recreate the first 15 row and 8 columns of the standard normal distribution.

I wish I could show and attempt, however I have no idea where to start

I know I will need for loops and one of the d,p,rnorm functions

If anyone could start me off or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you google first? https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/10/generating-your-own-normal-distribution-table/

Comment: BTW, that `wayne.edu` link is behind an auth-wall. While I discourage links in questions in general, even worse are links that don't work for the majority of viewers.

Comment: Nich, I recognize it is often difficult to "google" (or bing or ...) search for things related to the R programming language, since including `r` does ... almost nothing. However, you can narrow it down a bit by include `"r"` instead (double-quotes *require* that string), quotes can help narrow things quite a bit. See [`"r" standard "normal" table`](https://www.google.com/search?q="r"+standard+"normal"+table+&oq="r"+standard+"normal"+table) for many results, including rawr's r-bloggers link.

Comment: @r2evans i literally just copy and pasted the title of this question

Comment: that works as well :-)

Comment: Nich, have you tried using code in rawr's link? It's literally three lines of code, and you can generate all of it and then subset the results with `m[1:15,1:8]` (though I find it perplexing why you would want/need to omit the 0.8 and 0.9 columns on the right ...).

Comment: > u=seq(-3.9,-2.57,by=.01)
> p=pnorm(u)
> m=matrix(p,ncol=10,byrow=T)         This is the code that I tried using and it doesnt seem to give me the right values still is the problem

Comment: ANd thanks for the tips too:))

Comment: What do you mean, right values? Perhaps it's helpful to realize that some tables start with positives, some start with negatives ... some go most-negative to zero, some start at zero and go "outwards". What most people consider "right" for the "standard normal table" is based *heavily* on the table they first used learning statistics, so I believe you are making some assumptions about order and such that are just not true (or shared by everybody). What Z-scores do you need? Why are you cutting off the right two columns?

Comment: im looking at the standard normal table in it entirety [math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf] which is at this link, however I only want the rows from -3.9 to -2.5 and the columns from .00 to .07 because thats all I need it for, however the code doesnt seems to give the right standard values N(0,1)

Answer (score 0):

```
**x=seq(-3.9,-2.5,by=.1)
y=.01*(0:7)
f=matrix(NA,nrow=15,ncol=8)
for( i in 1:length(x)){
  for(j in 1:length(y)){
    f[i,j]=pnorm(x[i]-y[j])
  }
 }  
f
rounded=round(f,digits=5)
rownames(rounded)=seq(-3.9,-2.5,by=.1)
colnames(rounded)=seq(.00,.07,by=.01)
rounded**
```

This is the answer I wanted

This is how you make a STANDARD normal table N~(0,1), using any portion u want, in this case it is -3.9 to -2.57